# Use an existing PayPal App to receive payments with another account

Tags: paypal

I have a PayPal REST API App in my developer.paypal.com account. I need to change the PayPal account for this app.

Is this possible, or do I have to create a new PayPal developer account with the credentials of the customer?

Answer (score 0):

The customer who is going to receive payments should go to https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications , and create a new REST API App, and provide you with the Live mode Client ID and Secret.